# Using sort before group by in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am wondering if i can use sort before grouping in this type of query because i want the sort stage to use the index on `samples.timestamp1`

```
mydb1.mongodbbucketnocpu.aggregate(
  [
      {
          "$match": {
              "samples.timestamp1": {"$gte": datetime.strptime("2010-01-01 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),
                        "$lte": datetime.strptime("2015-01-01 01:55:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")},

          }
      },
{ "$unwind": "$samples" },

      {
          "$group": {

              "_id": {"$dateToString": {"format": "%Y-%m-%d %H", "date": "$samples.timestamp1"}},
              "max_id13": {
                  "$max": "$samples.id13"
              }
          }
      },
      {
          "$project": {
              "_id": 0,
              "day": "$_id",
              "max_id13": 1
          }
      },
      {"$sort": {"hour": -1}},
     { "$limit": 5}


    ]
)
```

My data contains about 96k documents that contain 12 subdocuments each.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("607f185f2a477a621641cded"),
    "nsamples" : 12,
    "samples" : [
        {
            "id1" : 3758,
            "id6" : 2,
            "id7" : -79.09,
            "id8" : 35.97,
            "id9" : 5.5,
            "id10" : 0,
            "id11" : -99999,
            "id12" : 0,
            "id13" : -9999,
            "c14" : "U",
            "id15" : 0,
            "id16" : 99,
            "id17" : 0,
            "id18" : -99,
            "id19" : -9999,
            "id20" : 33,
            "id21" : 0,
            "id22" : -99,
            "id23" : 0,
            "timestamp1" : ISODate("2010-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "timestamp2" : ISODate("2009-12-31T19:05:00Z")
        },
        {
            "id1" : 3758,
            "id6" : 2,
        .
        .
        .
```

When i tried using  `{"$sort": {"samples.timestamp1": -1}},` before group stage my output was this`Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes`
Is ti possible to use sort before group?What do you think i should do to optimize my query?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: If you want the items sorted within the documents generated by $group, sort before.  If you want the generated documents in a particular order, sort after.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Sure!

Comment: @joe Yes i want the generated documents in particular order but i also want to optimize the query so the sort can use the index

Comment: There is no way for an index to help with the documents that are dynamically generated by a group stage.

Comment: @joe so you mean if i want the output to be in a particular order sort cant use index right?

Comment: @joe can you confirm please?

Comment: Correct.  If there is group stage, no sorting using an index.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are only interested in `id13` and `timestamp1`, so as first stage I would suggest this:

```
db.mongodbbucketnocpu.aggregate([
  {$match: ... },
  {
    $set: {
      samples: {
        $map: {
          input: "$samples",
          in: { id13: "$$this.id13", timestamp1: "$$this.timestamp1" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$samples" },
  ...
])
```